# ArcGIS Desktop has stopped working

Tags: arcmap

I have been using ArcGIS and after sometimes suddenly it has stopped working.
When I tried to open ArcMap, it brings an error message:

> ArcGIS has stopped working. Please wait while gathering information about the error

then  nothing will appear afterwards.

I am using 10.7 version.
I have tried to reinstall, repair, but failed to work.

Has experienced the same error?

Comment: 10.7.1 is the terminal release of 10.7.x, but this could be as simple as a corrupted profile https://community.esri.com/docs/DOC-2121-resetting-your-arcgis-application-profile

Comment: Restarting your computer is also a good thing to try with weird Esri errors like this.

Comment: You may need to delete the `normal.mxt` file found somewhere under `C:\Users\<username>\AppData`

Comment: @Bjorn I considered that option but did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple reasons for the ArcMap to crash, to resolve the crash issue you can try the below workarounds:-

1. As mentioned by @Bjorn, try renaming the Normal.mxt file located in the users profile (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Esri\Desktop10.7\ArcMap\Templates), this will reset the application UI to its default.
2. If you have multiple graphics card on your machine, a conflict between them can also result in an ArcMap crash, kindly follow this article([Graphics card conflict](https://support.esri.com/en/Technical-Article/000013717)) for steps to follow.
3. Check if you can launch ArcCatalog, if that launches successfully without a crash you might want to look into the current default printer settings.
4. At the start menu open the services and stop the print spooler
   [image]
   [image]
5. Navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.7\bin\Configuration, and rename the CATID folder

**Note:- After each step try relaunching ArcMap and check if the crash issue is resolved.**

Comment: I have tried all your suggestions but the problem is still remains. I have two graphic cards and I tried to disable one after the other, but did not solve the problem. ArcCatalog also crashed like ArcMap when I tried to open it. I have restarted the PC several times plus reinstall ArcGIS but failed to fix the problem.

Comment: @sdm, try resetting the user profile, (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming), delete the ESRI folder